# Confusion with class diagram question

Tags: class-diagram

There was this question on my mock and I am just really confused about it. I tried to learn about class diagrams in more detail but there was no information that explained to the detail of the complexity of this class diagram, could someone please explain why the correct options for this question are correct and why the wrong options are incorrect, I would really appreciate it. I have spent very long trying to understand each option but I really don't understand it.

**The correct options are a, b and g, which I will highlight in bold**

**A property investor can invest in apartments, bungalows and houses and employs managers with responsibility for managing a selection of these properties.  The class diagram associated with this investor is as shown below.**

[image]

**Based on the above diagram, in the following, choose all statements which are true:**

***a. The association between Home Property and Investor is not owned by Financing Type.***

***b. A House could be managed by more than one Property Manager.***

c. Home Property is a type of House or Bungalow or Apartment.

d. Property portfolio consists of all types of properties.

e. Destroying Property portfolio destroys those properties that are within the collection.

f. A Property Manager manages all property types, and the collection could contain zero or more properties.

***g. Any number of Bungalow’s can be part of the Property portfolio.***

Comment: Rather than just posting the question, please explain your thought processes and what you think the answer is. We're prepared to help with homework questions, but we're not going to do all the work for you.

Comment: I already said I am completely lost and its not a homework question, it was a past question on a mock we did and I even said what the correct answers were in the question so you're not doing all the work for me. @PhilipKendall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding statement (a.) - it's a bit of a badly framed trick question/statement, IMO.

[image]

The dashed line connecting the association with `Ownership Type` indicates that this class and the association are one and the same (two representations of the same thing in the model). The association is not your usual field in the connected classes, instead, it is represented as a third class that somehow connects the other two (how exactly is not shown in the diagram), and contains some extra fields that are characterizing the association itself - in this case, the `Financing` field, that can be set to either "Cash" or "Mortgage".

In other words, if your association needs more than just a simple reference to some other object (like these other properties descriptive of the association itself), you can instead create a new class to explicitly represent the association. This kind of class is called an *association class*.

I suppose statement (a.) was meant to test your understanding of that. `Financing` is just a property on the association, while `Financing type` is a separate type that defines what `Financing` can be set to, and otherwise has no connection to the association. So it doesn't make sense to say that the association is "owned" by it (whatever that means).

Again, IMO, it's a bit of a curveball question, so if it doesn't entirely make sense to you, I wouldn't worry about it.

---

As for (b.), you have to focus on the multiplicities (numbers and stars) written between `Property Manager` and `Property Portfolio`:

[image]

A `Property Manager` is connected with a `House` (specifically, with a `Regular` house) through a `Property Portfolio`. Now, the multiplicity indicated by `*` can be read as "many", "zero or more". A `*` near a box indicates (potentially) *many* instances of that box. As in, a single `Property Manager` could be potentially connected to more than one `Property Portfolio`. And likewise, if you read it in the other direction, it also says that a single `Property Portfolio` could have more than one `Property Manager`. The relationship is many-to-many.

So, (b.) is correct since a house is found in a `Property Portfolio`, and a portfolio can be associated with more than one manager.

This same reasoning about multiplicity leads you to conclude that (g.) is correct - there's a `*` next to the `Bungalow` box (a `Property Portfolio` can be associated with many `Bungalow`-s). In the other direction, it says that each bungalow is only in a single portfolio.

---

The statement (c.) is incorrect because it's the other way around: `House`, `Bungalow` and `Apartment` are all different (sub)types of `Home Property`.

---

For (d.) and (f.), note that `Property Portfolio` is not connected to all subtypes of `Home Property`. In (f.), the "the collection could contain zero or more properties" part is, I think, a red herring.

---

Finally, (e.) is about whether or not different kinds of housing properties can exist (within the computer system in question) independently of the `Property Portfolio`. E.g. imagine you're using this software - if you delete the portfolio, do you want the system to also delete all the houses, apartments and bungalows that were in there as well? You might want to keep them in the database, and maybe place them in some other portfolio. (Another example: if you delete a playlist, do you want to delete all the songs as well?)

This possibility of independent existence is indicated by the white (unfilled) diamonds at the association ends near the `Property Portfolio`. If the diamonds were filled, then that would mean that `Property Portfolio` "owns" the other instances and is responsible for managing their lifecycle.

Comment: Fantastic explanation Filip thank you so so much. Just two quick questions. For A, if the option was "The association between Home Property and Investor is not owned by Ownership Type" would this be incorrect? Is the association owned by Ownership Type which is the class NOT financing type? Secondly, how is B correct when there is only a line from regular and not luxury, the option says "a house", surely that should include luxury too but there is no line from luxury to Property Portfolio?...

Comment: ...Since you say "Property Portfolio is not connected to all subtypes of Home Property" hence D and F are incorrect, why is this same reasoning not used for B? Thank you

Comment: @jasmineoverflow "Is the association owned by Ownership Type" - well, that's where it gets tricky. In UML, if I'm not mistaken, there's no notion of association ownership. The specification regards an association as having two ends, and then talks about the ownership of those *ends* (which is a whole other confusing can of worms that people more or less ignore in practice). I personally would *not* say that the association in question is owned by the type connected to it by the dashed line; conceptually, this box just another representation of the association - a "zoomed in" view of it. 1/3

Comment: @jasmineoverflow The important thing is that the association itself is between Home Property and Investor. It's not "owned" by anything. (Also, don't get confused by the name "Ownership type" - the name could be anything.) This is why I said it's a bit of a curveball question. /// Regarding (b.) - I can only assume that the person who wrote the question primarily intended to test your understanding of multiplicities there, and didn't perceive the exclusion of Luxury subtrype as important. Perhaps the question was poorly worded. While confusing, this is not entirely unreasonable. 2/3

Comment: @jasmineoverflow The line with an unfilled triangle arrow indicates inheritance, which is an "is-a" relationship. Regular & Luxury are each to be understood as a kind of House (regular house "is-a" house). So (b.) can perhaps be interpreted as containing an implicit "of those houses that can have managers". Again, I think what happened is that the person who wrote the question didn't consider that their wording might confuse people who are just learning, or maybe they assumed an interview environment (rather than a written test) where one can have a discussion, ask for clarification, etc. 3/3